# How to format numeric values with separators starting at 1,000 instead of 10,000 using Intl.NumberFormat?

Tags: javascript, formatting, number-formatting

I have the following function:

```
formatNumericValues() {
    const numberFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat('es', {
      minimumFractionDigits: 0,
      maximumFractionDigits: 2,
    });

    this.tableItems.forEach((item) => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax
      for (const key in item) {
        if (typeof item[key] === 'number') {
          let formattedValue = numberFormat.format(item[key]);

          if (item[key] % 1 !== 0) { // Verifica si el número tiene decimales
            formattedValue = item[key].toFixed(2).replace(/\./g, ',');
          } else {
            formattedValue = formattedValue.replace(/\.00$/, '');
          }

          item[key] = formattedValue;
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

I want the '.' to be placed starting at 1,000, but it is doing so starting at 10,000. I have tried placing the following without success:

```
const numberFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat('en', {
      minimumFractionDigits: 0,
      maximumFractionDigits: 2,
      minimumSignificantDigits: 1,
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`useGrouping`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat#usegrouping) constructor option to always show the grouping separator. Here's an example:

```js
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("es-ES", { useGrouping: "always" });

for (
  const n of Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, i) => 10 ** i)
) console.log(formatter.format(n));
/* Logs:
            1
           10
          100
        1.000
       10.000
      100.000
    1.000.000
   10.000.000
  100.000.000
1.000.000.000
*/
```

Comment: Just a note, this works nicely in Chrome for me, but not in Firefox (113.0.1). Which is a little weird, though at least the great majority of users will see the desired result.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76288664/how-to-format-numeric-values-with-separators-starting-at-1-000-instead-of-10-000/76288925?noredirect=1#comment134529874_76288925) @TerryLennox Thanks for the feedback. "_but not in Firefox_": What exactly do you see in FF?

Comment: In Chrome, 1000 is formatted as '1.000', in Firefox as '1000'. The other numbers are formatted the same in both browsers.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76288664/how-to-format-numeric-values-with-separators-starting-at-1-000-instead-of-10-000/76288925?noredirect=1#comment134530043_76288925) @TerryLennox It's a bit disappointing that FF's implementation is not consistent. I appreciate your comment —thanks!

Comment: Very annoying! I'd see that as a FF bug perhaps. Though maybe they are just using a different interpretation of the rules for the locale.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to jsejcksn's answer:

The Spanish locale has `minimumGroupingDigits = 2` (see [here](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/e46774fcb6eaea3c106b29e7011d68c8749aefbb/common/main/es.xml#L5869)), which means that no "thousands grouping character" will be inserted if there would be fewer than two digits before it. Read the explanation [here](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-numbers.html#Examples_of_minimumGroupingDigits).

For comparison, the German locale has `minimumGroupingDigits = 1` (see [here](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/e46774fcb6eaea3c106b29e7011d68c8749aefbb/common/main/de.xml#L5891)):

```js
console.log(
  Intl.NumberFormat("es").format(1000),
  Intl.NumberFormat("de").format(1000)
);
```

Comment: The problem has been solved. I am dumping the data in a table and they are sorted by the name of the municipality, but if I sort them by inhabitant, they are not sorted correctly.